# Is it true that every open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is a countable union of disjoint connected open sets?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it true that every open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is a countable union of disjoint connected open sets?

That is if $A\subset\mathbb{C}$ then $A=\bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty}U_{i}$ where $U_{i}$ are pairwise disjoint, connected, open sets?

Comment: If you allow $U_i = \varnothing$ then yes, otherwise you'd need to allow for open sets with finitely many components. The point is that $\mathbb{C}$ is second countable and locally connected.

Comment: The notion of connected components means that all you have to prove is the "countable" union. In each connected component, choose a complex number whose real and imaginary parts are rational numbers. This is an injection from the set of connected components into $\Bbb Q^2$; hence the set of connected components is countable.

Comment: So given the rest, countable can be show as you say @GregMartin, however my problem is with the pairwise disjoint, connected, open sets part. Please have patients with me, i haven't read any topology.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read these posts before writing my answers; I did not mean to ripoff  from the comments.

Comment: Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $A$ by: $x\sim y$ if there exists a connected subset of $A$ containing both $x$ and $y$. The equivalence classes under this relation are the connected components of $A$. (It's a good exercise to check everything in those two sentences.) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\mathbb C$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ , and so it is 2nd countable. This implies that every connected component is the countable union of open sets. And every open set can have at most countably-many components.